# Django inernal server Error

Tags: django

I'm working on a Django website.
When I upload an image and its name is in English, it will be uploaded. But when I try to in Arabic it can't upload, it gives an internal server error.

Comment: set DEBUG=True, and add full error trace to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got unicode error in server.
So set both in system environment then check.

```
LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/django_apache_and_mod_wsgi#AdditionalTweaking